# Cannot convert type 'Umbraco.Core.Dynamics.DynamicNull' to 'Umbraco.....' - Umbraco v6

Tags: c#, dynamic, umbraco

I've looked at a couple of similar errors regarding `IPublishedContent` (yes I know this is a different object than what I'm using) in Umbraco, and they've all said it's been fixed since 4.11.7 - however, I'm using v6 so obviously that's not the case.

- [Case 1](http://issues.umbraco.org/issue/U4-1300)
- [Case 2](http://issues.umbraco.org/issue/U4-2045)

My code worked until I threw in a coalesce:

**Worked:**

```
DynamicPublishedContent countryFolder = Umbraco.Media(CurrentPage.GetProperty("contestMediaFolder").Value.ToString());
```

**No longer works:**

```
DynamicPublishedContent countryFolder = !string.IsNullOrEmpty(contestFolder)
                                             ? Umbraco.Media(CurrentPage.GetProperty("contestMediaFolder").Value.ToString())
                                             : Umbraco.Media(contestFolder);
```

*Cannot convert type 'Umbraco.Core.Dynamics.DynamicNull' to 'Umbraco.Web.Models.DynamicPublishedContent'*

I have (2) controllers that are calling the same code, one is a controller that is hit on page load, the other is an API controller. This is the reason I'm passing in the variable, `contestFolder`, which is a `string`, since this method returns a list. In my method call, I'm also passing in `string.Empty`, which would run the first line.

I've tried:

- Replacing the strongly typed object, `DynamicPublishedContent` with
  `var`.
- Passing in an `int` rather than a `string` to the method
  (`contestFolder` would be an int).
- Casting both returns on the `Umbraco.Media()` to
  `DynamicPublishedContent`
- Instead of using `DynamicPublishedContent`, use
  `IPublishedContent` object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I switched out how I retrieved the folder. I singled out the reason, and it's b/c if regardless if that 2nd coalesce hits, Umbraco attempts to retrieve the folder, and if it's null, it returns that error,

*Cannot convert type 'Umbraco.Core.Dynamics.DynamicNull' to 'Umbraco.Web.Models.DynamicPublishedContent'*

Therefore, you HAVE to pass an actual media id (that's valid) to the `Umbraco.Media()` method, or you'll have this error returned to you.

```
public override ActionResult Index(RenderModel model)
{
    var entries = this.GetContestEntries(this.GetCountryFolder(CurrentPage.GetProperty("contestMediaFolder").Value.ToString()));

    return base.Index(model);
}

public DynamicPublishedContent GetCountryFolder(string countryFolder)
{
    return (DynamicPublishedContent)Umbraco.Media(countryFolder);
}

public List<WAR2015ContestModel> GetContestEntries(DynamicPublishedContent countryFolder)
{
     .....  // code omitted
}
```